# How to make a js script run only once/restricted amounts of time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension I have code that does the following:

```
-> User goes to website -> 
-> User sees a list of URLs to tables, they click one -> 
-> My script opens a new tab in response to scraping the table.
```

This works well, but in the last step where I open a new tab, I would like the tab I open to only be opened **once in the lifetime of the extension**. So the first time the user clicks the URL to the table, the tab opens for them, then never again. How can I accomplish this?

For clarity and to avoid downvotes this is the code I want to run only once

```
window.open(URL, '_blank')
```

Comment: Use chrome.storage API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a boolean in the extension script.

```
var done = true;
```

And then perform a check whenever user clicks the url:

```
if (!done) {
    //open tab
}
```

To store the value, you can use `localStorage`

```js
window.localStorage.setItem("done", true);
```

And then whenever you are performing the check:

```js
if (!window.localStorage.getItem("done")) {
    //open tab
}
```

Comment: But don't variables refresh whenever you go to a new site? Then the done would be reset wouldn't it?

Comment: If you want to store it permanently, you can use `localStorage`. I'll add that too.

Comment: How about having  a localStorage array and adding to it?

Comment: Then you could `window.localStorage.setItem("doneArr", [true, true, false, true])`

Comment: Do I just push new items onto it then? In order to add new elems to it

Comment: i doubt it would be that simple. I think you should first get the whole array like `var arr = window.localStorage.getItem("doneArr");`. Then push on to the variable `arr.Push(true);`. And finally, set item to the variable `window.localStorage.setItem("doneArr", arr);`.